# Calculating probabilities in XGBoost

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, xgboost, predict

I'm getting started with XGBoost in R, and am trying to match up the predictions from the *binary:logistic* model with what's generated by using a custom log loss function. I'd expect the following two calls to *predict* to generate the same results:

```
require(xgboost)

loglossobj <- function(preds, dtrain) {
  labels <- getinfo(dtrain, "label")
  preds <- 1/(1 + exp(-preds))
  grad <- preds - labels
  hess <- preds * (1 - preds)
  return(list(grad = grad, hess = hess))
}

data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')
train<-agaricus.train
test<-agaricus.test

model<-xgboost(data = train$data, label = train$label, nrounds=2,objective="binary:logistic")
preds = predict(model,test$data)
print (head(preds))

model<-xgboost(data = train$data, label = train$label, nrounds=2,objective=loglossobj, eval_metric = "error")
preds = predict(model,test$data)
x = 1 / (1+exp(-preds))
print (head(x))
```

The model output from a custom log loss function does not have the logistic transformation 1/(1+exp(-x)) applied. However, if I do so the resulting probabilities are different between the two calls to *predict*:

```
[1] 0.2582498 0.7433221 0.2582498 0.2582498 0.2576509 0.2750908
```

versus

```
[1] 0.3076240 0.7995583 0.3076240 0.3076240 0.3079328 0.3231709
```

I'm sure there's a simple explanation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this behaviour is due to initial conditions. xgboost implicitly assumes base_score=0.5 when calling *binary:logistic* or *binary:logit_raw*, but *base_score* must be set to 0.0 to replicate their output when using a custom loss function. Here, base_score is the initial prediction score of all instances.

To illustrate, the following R code generates the same predictions in all three cases:

```
require(xgboost)

loglossobj <- function(preds, dtrain) {
  labels <- getinfo(dtrain, "label")
  preds <- 1/(1 + exp(-preds))
  grad <- preds - labels
  hess <- preds * (1 - preds)
  return(list(grad = grad, hess = hess))
}

data(agaricus.train, package='xgboost')
data(agaricus.test, package='xgboost')
train<-agaricus.train
test<-agaricus.test

model<-xgboost(data = train$data, label = train$label, objective = "binary:logistic", nround = 10, eta = 0.1, verbose=0)
preds = predict(model,test$data)
print (head(preds))

model<-xgboost(data = train$data, label = train$label, objective = "binary:logitraw", nround = 10, eta = 0.1, verbose=0)
preds = predict(model,test$data)
x = 1 / (1+exp(-preds))
print (head(x))

model<-xgboost(data = train$data, label = train$label, objective = loglossobj, base_score = 0.0, nround = 10, eta = 0.1, verbose=0)
preds = predict(model,test$data)
x = 1 / (1+exp(-preds))
print (head(x))
```

which outputs

```
[1] 0.1814032 0.8204284 0.1814032 0.1814032 0.1837782 0.1952717
[1] 0.1814032 0.8204284 0.1814032 0.1814032 0.1837782 0.1952717
[1] 0.1814032 0.8204284 0.1814032 0.1814032 0.1837782 0.1952717
```